Why aren't my equal signs aligned with one another?
I'm very new to using LaTeX. I am trying to write a simple page with equations. The issue is that my equal signs are not aligned with each other. I am using Overleaf. Thanks in advance for the help.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm,marginparwidth=1.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
1. Self-weight formula for $n$ number of cutouts:
\[SW = (2\rho_fgblt+\rho_cgblc)-n(2\rho_fg\beta^2t+\rho_cg\beta^2c)\]
Where:
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{ccl}\
$\rho_f$ & = & Density of the steel face (S280GD+ZM140) at \num{7850e-9} kg/mm$^3$ \\
$\rho_c$ & = & Density of the expanded polystyrene (EPS) at \num{40e-9} kg/mm$^3$ \\
$g$ & = & Gravitational constant of 9.81 m/s$^2$ \\ 
$b$ & = & Fixed width of the sandwich panel at 1150 mm \\
$l$ & = & Span length of the panel in mm \\
$t$ & = & Fixed thickness of the steel face at 0.51 mm \\
$c$ & = & Thickness of the EPS core in mm \\ 
$\beta^2$ & = & Area of the square cutout fixed at $570^2$ mm \\
\end{tabular}\end{center}

2. Equivalent flexural rigidity:
\[EI_{eq} = \frac{E_fbtc^2}{2} \]
Where:
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{ccl}\
$E_f$ & = & Elastic modulus of the steel face at \num{204e-9} MPa \\
$b$ & = & Fixed width of the sandwich panel at 1150 mm \\
$t$ & = & Fixed thickness of the steel face at 0.51 mm \\
$c$ & = & Thickness of the EPS core in mm \\
\end{tabular}\end{center}

3. Equivalent shear rigidity:
\[AG_{eq} = bcG_c\]
Where:
\begin{center}\begin{tabular}{ccl}\
$b$ & = & Fixed width of the sandwich panel at 1150 mm \\
$c$ & = & Thickness of the EPS core in mm \\
$G_c$ & = & Shear modulus of the EPS core at 2.40 MPa \\
\end{tabular}\end{center}
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE.

Why are you using tabular environments instead of align* environments?

... or maybe a simple itemize with no labels.

Off-topic: the option list top=2cm,bottom=2cm,left=3cm,right=3cm may be expressed more succinctly as vmargin=2cm,hmargin=3cm.

The equal signs are aligned in this output.  Or are you wanting each of the three sets to also align with each other?  (Note that your marginparwidth is causing an error because you need units after 1.75.)

I'd not align the main equations, just the explanations.
Use \qty and not just \num.
The \where command takes advantage of the uniformity in the explanations, so each row has a first part to be typeset in math mode and followed by =; the second part is in standard text mode.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  top=2cm,
  bottom=2cm,
  left=3cm,
  right=3cm,
  marginparwidth=1.75cm,% <-- don't forget the unit
]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}

\sisetup{per-mode=symbol}

\newcommand\rhof{\rho^{}_{\!f}} % good trick by Mico

\NewDocumentCommand{\where}{m}{%
  \par
  \setlength{\dimen0}{-\lastskip}% the space below the equation
  \nopagebreak % no page break here
  \vspace{\dimen0}% remove the space
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{} >{$}w{r}{3pc}<{={}$} @{} l @{}}
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}l@{}}{where} \\[1ex]
  #1
  \end{tabular}\par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[parsep=0pt]
\item Self-weight formula for $n$ number of cutouts:
\[
\mathit{SW} = (2\rhof gblt+\rho_cgblc)-n(2\rhof g\beta^2t+\rho_cg\beta^2c
\]
\where{
  \rhof   & Density of the steel face (S280GD+ZM140),
            at \qty{7850e-9}{\kilo\gram\per\milli\meter\cubed} \\
  \rho_c  & Density of the expanded polystyrene (EPS),
            at \qty{40e-9}{\kilo\gram\per\milli\meter\cubed} \\
  g       & Gravitational constant of \qty{9.81}{\meter\per\second\squared} \\ 
  b       & Fixed width of the sandwich panel, at \qty{1150}{\milli\meter} \\
  l       & Span length of the panel, in \unit{\milli\meter} \\
  t       & Fixed thickness of the steel face, at \qty{0.51}{\milli\meter} \\
  c       & Thickness of the EPS core, in \unit{\milli\meter} \\ 
  \beta^2 & Area of the square cutout, fixed at \qty{570}{\milli\meter\squared}
}
\item Equivalent flexural rigidity:
\[
\mathit{EI}_{\mathrm{eq}} = \frac{1}{2} E_fbtc^2
\]
\where{
  E_f & Elastic modulus of the steel face at \qty{204e-9}{\mega\pascal} \\
  b   & Fixed width of the sandwich panel at \qty{1150}{\milli\meter} \\
  t   & Fixed thickness of the steel face at \qty{0.51}{\milli\meter} \\
  c   & Thickness of the EPS core, in \unit{\milli\meter} \\
}
\item Equivalent shear rigidity:
\[
\mathit{AG}_{\mathrm{eq}} = bcG_c
\]
\where{
  b   & Fixed width of the sandwich panel at \qty{1150}{\milli\meter} \\
  c   & Thickness of the EPS core, in \unit{\milli\meter} \\
  G_c & Shear modulus of the EPS core at \qty{2.40}{\mega\pascal} \\
}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}



Here's a solution that employs an enumerate environment with three \item directives and three align* environments. Also, since you employ the siunitx package, do start using its \unit and \qty macros in addition to the \num macro.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=2cm,hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item Self-weight formula for $n$ number of cutouts:
\[
\mathit{SW} = (2\rho^{}_{\!f}gblt+\rho_cgblc)-n(2\rho^{}_{\!f}g\beta^2t+\rho_cg\beta^2c)
\]
where
\begin{align*}
\rho^{}_{\!f} &= \text{Density of the steel face (S280GD+ZM140), at \qty{7850e-9}{\kilo\gram\per\milli\meter\cubed}} \\
\rho_c &= \text{Density of the expanded polystyrene (EPS), at \qty{40e-9}{\kilo\gram\per\milli\meter\cubed}} \\
g &= \text{Gravitational constant of \qty{9.81}{\meter\per\second\squared}} \\ 
b &= \text{Fixed width of the sandwich panel, at \qty{1150}{\milli\meter}} \\
l &= \text{Span length of the panel, in \unit{\milli\meter}} \\
t &= \text{Fixed thickness of the steel face, at \qty{0.51}{\milli\meter}} \\
c &= \text{Thickness of the EPS core, in \unit{\milli\meter}} \\ 
\beta^2 &= \text{Area of the square cutout, fixed at \qty{570}{\milli\meter\squared}} 
\end{align*}

\item Equivalent flexural rigidity:
\[
\mathit{EI}_{\mathrm{eq}} = \tfrac{1}{2} E_fbtc^2
\]
where
\begin{align*}
E_f &= \text{Elastic modulus of the steel face at \qty{204e-9}{\mega\pascal}} \\
b &= \text{Fixed width of the sandwich panel at \qty{1150}{\milli\meter}} \\
t &= \text{Fixed thickness of the steel face at \qty{0.51}{\milli\meter}} \\
c &= \text{Thickness of the EPS core, in \unit{\milli\meter}}
\end{align*}

\item Equivalent shear rigidity:
\[
\mathit{AG}_{\mathrm{eq}} = bcG_c
\]
where
\begin{align*}
b &= \text{Fixed width of the sandwich panel at \qty{1150}{\milli\meter}} \\
c &= \text{Thickness of the EPS core, in \unit{\milli\meter}} \\
G_c &= \text{Shear modulus of the EPS core at \qty{2.40}{\mega\pascal}}
\end{align*}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


Addendum: @Teepeemm has commented that the OP may want to align all equations on their = symbols -- across the entire enumerate environment. This may be accomplished with the following code, which uses a single align* environment instead of three separate align* environments. Speaking for myself [who else?], I wouldn't say that this "fully-aligned" variant is noticeably better than the initial solution.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,vmargin=2cm,hmargin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools} % 'mathtools' is superset of 'amsmath'
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[per-mode=symbol,tight-spacing]{siunitx}
\newcommand\rhof{\rho^{}_{\!f}}
\begin{document}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{enumerate}[noitemsep]
\item Self-weight formula for $n$ number of cutouts:
\begin{align*}
\mathit{SW} &= (2\rhof gblt+\rho_cgblc)-n(2\rhof g\beta^2t+\rho_cg\beta^2c) \\
\shortintertext{where}
\rhof &= \text{Density of the steel face (S280GD+ZM140), at \qty{7850e-9}{\kilo\gram\per\milli\meter\cubed}} \\
\rho_c &= \text{Density of the expanded polystyrene (EPS), at \qty{40e-9}{\kilo\gram\per\milli\meter\cubed}} \\
g &= \text{Gravitational constant of \qty{9.81}{\meter\per\second\squared}} \\ 
b &= \text{Fixed width of the sandwich panel, at \qty{1150}{\milli\meter}} \\
l &= \text{Span length of the panel, in \unit{\milli\meter}} \\
t &= \text{Fixed thickness of the steel face, at \qty{0.51}{\milli\meter}} \\
c &= \text{Thickness of the EPS core, in \unit{\milli\meter}} \\ 
\beta^2 &= \text{Area of the square cutout, fixed at \qty{570}{\milli\meter\squared}} \\
\intertext{
\item Equivalent flexural rigidity:}
\mathit{EI}_{\mathrm{eq}} &= \tfrac{1}{2} E_fbtc^2 \\
\shortintertext{where}
E_f &= \text{Elastic modulus of the steel face at \qty{204e-9}{\mega\pascal}} \\
b &= \text{Fixed width of the sandwich panel at \qty{1150}{\milli\meter}} \\
t &= \text{Fixed thickness of the steel face at \qty{0.51}{\milli\meter}} \\
c &= \text{Thickness of the EPS core, in \unit{\milli\meter}} \\
\intertext{
\item Equivalent shear rigidity:}
\mathit{AG}_{\mathrm{eq}} &= bcG_c\\
\shortintertext{where}
b &= \text{Fixed width of the sandwich panel at \qty{1150}{\milli\meter}} \\
c &= \text{Thickness of the EPS core, in \unit{\milli\meter}} \\
G_c &= \text{Shear modulus of the EPS core at \qty{2.40}{\mega\pascal}}
\end{align*}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}


@Teepeemm - Thanks. I've gone ahead and posted a second solution, which aligns all = symbols. Let's see if the OP weighs in with some clarifying information as to what the formatting objective is.

This looks absolutely perfect. All 3 sets being aligned was indeed the objective here. Thank you all for your generous help!
